# How to integrate TCS api with odoo 9

Tags: api, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9

Please tell me how to integrate TCS Api in Odoo . I have some nominal code but i don't know this is a APi or not . If this is a Api then please tell me how i use this Code

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 202.61.51.93
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://202.61.51.93:6265/GetAllCountries"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAllCountries xmlns="http://202.61.51.93:6265/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAllCountriesResponse xmlns="http://202.61.51.93:6265/">
      <GetAllCountriesResult>xmlxml</GetAllCountriesResult>
    </GetAllCountriesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is TCS? What exactly do you want to do? Parse SOAP request? Which are the placeholders in this text?

Comment: TCS is a courier service , I want to integrate its API.

Comment: how to hit web server api ...

Comment: Sir Please check it `http://202.61.51.93:6265/` and tell me about it. is it a API or not

Comment: length and xml.xml are place holder there.